# Prove that $n!\leq(\frac{n}{2})^n$ for all $n\geq 6$

Tags: number-theory

This is what I have so far. How do I continue the induction step?

For n=6, this is true since $720\leq 729$
Suppose $n!\leq(\frac{n}{2})^n$ holds for all $n\geq 6$
Want to prove that it holds for n+1, That is $(n+1)!\leq(\frac{n+1}{2})^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 6$

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519559) (among several mutual duplicates) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144176).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we check the base case. That is, as you showed, the statement is true for $n=6$. Indeed:
$$ 6! \leq (\frac{6}{2}^6) $$
$$ \implies 720 \leq 3^6 = 729 $$
Now we assume that the given statement is true for an arbitrary element $k$ in the set of Natural Numbers $\mathbb N$. So we suppose

$$ k! \leq (\frac{k}{2})^k \ \ k \geq 6$$

is a true statement. Now, if we show this statement also holds for $n = k+1$ then we are done. That is, we want to show

$$ (k+1)! \leq (\frac{k+1}{2})^{k+1}  $$

Now remember, for example, we can write $5!$ as $5 \cdot 4!$. Therefore, we can write

$$ (k+1)! = k!\cdot (k+1) $$

Now what do we know about $k!$? Well we assumed $k! \leq (\frac{k}{2})^k$. So we can write

$$(k+1)! = k! \cdot (k+1) \leq (\frac{k}{2})^k \cdot (k+1)$$

The last thing we need to do is to show $(\frac{k}{2})^k \leq \frac{(k+1)^k}{2^{k+1}}$. I will leave this to you, but you could convince yourself it is the case. Keep in mind $k \geq 6$.

Putting the pieces together, it follows 
$$(k+1)! \leq (\frac{k+1}{2})^{k+1}$$

This shows the statement is true by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** So as $n! \leq(\frac{n}{2})^n$ (from the induction assumption), we have $(n+1)! = n! (n+1)\leq(\frac{n}{2})^n (n+1) = \frac{n^n(n+1)}{2^n}$. Now it is enough to prove that $\frac{n^n}{2^n} \leq \frac{(n+1)^n}{2^{n+1}} \Leftrightarrow n^n \leq \frac{(n+1)^n}{2}$. Get $\log$ from two side:
$$n\log(n) \leq n \log(n+1) - \log(2) \Leftrightarrow log(2) \leq n (\log(n+1)-\log(n)) = n\log(\frac{n+1}{n}) \\ \Leftrightarrow 2 \leq (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$$.

As $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ increases monotonoically (you can see for $x > 0$ the derivative function of $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ is greater than zero) and for $n = 6$ we have $(1+\frac{1}{6})^6 > 2.5$ you can prove the inequality.